# MySQL: Can I update a record in a current result set or do I need 2 parallel queries/connections

Tags: mysql, c, connection

I am writing a C app which retrieves a number of records using one select statement.  After issuing the query, I retrieve these records using mysql_use_result then repeat mysql_fetch_row.

This is working fine, but now I want to update each record after I retrieve it.  My options as I see them (but perhaps not technically possible) are:

1. Issue a second sql query to update that one record, while the first result set is still in use  (But, if I issue a second query will it screw up the result set from my first query??)
2. Open another connection, then issue another sql query to update that one record.  (But, can I open two connections from the same process to the same SQL server, and will is screw up the first connection?)
3. Change my first query to retrieve one record at a time, free the result set, and then issue a second query to update the record, and then repeat.  This seems inefficient.  (Can I reuse the same connection after I mysql_free_result?)

What is possible?  What is the right way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also read all rows, remember the updates you need to make, and issue the updates afterwards. The best way might be to issue a single update statement that updates all the rows at once. Whether this is possible depends on what exactly you need to update.

Comment: Each row is being updated a bit differently, so saving for later or bulk update won't work.  Sounds like you're saying option 3 is the only way to go.  Can I reuse the same connection after a mysql_free_result?

Comment: @Michelle Dupuis: SQL supports updating multiple rows at once and setting a different value for each row. You can for example join with a table (or derived table) containing the values by using the multi-table syntax. See the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html